# openshift does not honor the USER directive in Dockerfile

Tags: kubernetes, openshift-origin

I'm new to Openshift/k8s. The docker image I'm running in openshift is using USER blabla.  But when I exec into the pod, it use a different rather than the one in Dockerfile.

I'm wondering why? and how can I work around this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For security, cluster administrators have the option to force containers to run with cluster assigned uids. By default, most containers run using a uid from a range assigned to the project.

This is controlled by the configured [SecurityContextConstraints](https://docs.openshift.org/latest/admin_guide/manage_scc.html).

To allow containers to run as the user declared in their dockerfile (even though this can expose the cluster, security-wise), allow the pod's service account access to the anyuid SecurityContextConstraint (`oadm policy add-scc-to-user anyuid system:serviceaccount:<your ns>:<your service account>`

Comment: with openshift 4 CLI: "oc adm policy add-scc-to-user anyuid -n my_project_namespace -z default", where 'default ' is indeed the default service account that executes pods in a project